# Comp. stuck at blinking cursor DOS screen every other time i turn on computer, what's the most likely issue?

Tags: boot, memory, windows-10-preview

I'm running a desktop computer with a fully updated Windows 10. Before I had a problem where it would get stuck at the GIGABYTE BIOS screen and i removed one of the ram sticks (i had an excessive amount of RAM anyways) and the problem was solved.

It used to be that my computer would only get stuck at the blinking cursor DOS style screen every once in a while, but I still wanted to fix this problem so i bought some RAM off Ebay, and it fixed the problem for a while. However, after a month it came back, and now this problem occurs *every other time I turn on the computer*. To get windows 10 to start i have to hit the reset button on the front of my case. Today I tried removing the graphics card all together, and putting my previous good ram stick back in along with the new ram i bought, and nothing has changed.

It's significant to note that putting the computer to sleep and starting the system up again doesn't create this problem. Also, I have ran a diagnostic on my processor and it seems to be just fine.

This isn't the end of the world, i just reset the computer every time i turn it on, but it still troubles me. I would like to have computer I can reliably turn off. So far the possible culprits seem to be one of these:

-the motherboard

-the RAM slots of the motherboard

-Windows 10

-maybe some electrical issue, the power outlets in my house are always going on
the fritz. I was having an issue for a while because my computer was plugged into a power strip that was plugged into the wall, and when my dog stepped on the power strip the computer would shut off all-together, so i had to plug in a surge protector to keep the problem from happening.

Hopefully, one of you with a more industry-level knowledge of computers will be able to provide interesting insights and discussions. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't specify the model of your motherboard. This sounds like a possible timing issue. When you power the computer on, the drive(s) do not spin up and become available fast enough for the motherboard. After a reset, they are already running and available. There should be an option in your BIOS to delay boot for a few seconds, some times it is specifically worded and located in a way as to be a fix for this exact problem. You may also look at disabling a "Fast Boot" option if it exists, which might introduce sufficient delay.

Comment: The mobo is GIGABYTE GA-H170M-D3H DDR3 LGA1151/ Intel H170/ DDR3/ 2-Way CrossFireX/. After reading what you said i fixed the problem...the issue was that i had a samsung camera plugged into the computer, and the BIOS had this listed as the first boot option, so now that i've removed the camera i no longer have this problem, thank you much appleoddity. Cheers to my problem free computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was fixed by removing a device that was first in the bios boot order.

Comment: the question is certainly not off topic, close the question as answered.

Comment: @DavidPostill how is this question off topic? That’s a bit of an overreach of power there. At least allow the OP to answer their own question.

Comment: @Katz_Katz_Katz Questions should not be answered in comments. I've reopened the question so your can  [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was caused entirely by the fact that the BIOS was trying to boot from my SAMSUNG camera. If you run into this problem, you can simply remove the device your computer is trying to boot from, or you can go into the BIOS by pressing the F9, F2, F10, or F12 key on most computers at startup and change the boot order so that it boots from your hard drive instead.

Comment: You can flag your own post as an answer, and you should.